# How does the "French Defense, Winawer Variation, Fingerslip Variation" get its name?

Tags: opening, history, terminology, french-defense

Why is [this](http://chesstempo.com/gamedb/opening/712) particular iteration of the "French Defense, Winawer Variation" called the "Fingerslip Variation"?

```
[fen "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. Nc3 Bb4 4. Bd2
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to "The Batsford Guide to Chess Openings" by Leonard Barden and Tim Harding:

"This move had its introduction into master play as the result of a fingerslip by Alekhine against Flohr, at Nottingham in 1936. He had intended 4 P-K5 P-QB4 5 B-Q2, but played the moves in the wrong order"

The game is at

http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1008345

Comment: There were earlier occurrences in master play: Marshall-Chigorin, Monte Carlo (1901) and Speijer-Alekhine(!), Hamburg (1910).

Comment: In algebraic notation, that's 4.e5 c5 5.Bd2.